# Java Swing: ImageIcon not appearing in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am designing a GUI. I have created a Menubar and added Menu items to Menu and Have setMenubar.
My problem is i am not able to add an icon (icon is not appearing in eclipse) to the Menuitem.

This is how I did:
I have my .png file in D:/something/src/resources/new.png

```
JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
JMenu File = new JMenu("File");
menuBar.add(File);
java.net.URL imageURL = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/new.png");
System.out.println(imageURL); //imageURL is printing correctly in console
ImageIcon im = new ImageIcon(imageURL);
JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem("New", im);

File.add(newItem);
setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

I am facing the similar problem adding icon to a button in Toolbar too. Guess, it is same cause. Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Note: I have tried with .jpg, .jpeg and .ico files too. But nothing is appearing in eclipse!. I am using Windows & MS Access database.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1):

A file in resources would typically end up at the root of a Jar.  Try:

```
java.net.URL imageURL = this.getClass().getResource("/new.png");
```

If that fails for you, expand the Jar and check the image is located where you *think* it is.

Comment: Hmm ... if the url isn't null (as proven by printing it), the resource is found. Wondering what else could go wrong (@Anna Marie)

Comment: @kleopatra  I had not noticed the comment in the line after the one I was looking at! :(

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the resources folder, is the Source Folder that you had created by right clicking your Project. So you can use this also to retrieve images.

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path);
```

where path = "new.png"

Or as quoted by you :

**"This is how I did: I have my .png file in D:/something/src/resources/new.png"**
Try to change the location of the resources folder inside classes/bin folder instead of src. So it must look like this D:/something/classes/resources/new.png
Now if you will use

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(path);
```

then path = "resources/new.png";

Then i guess your way of doing will run too.

Hopefully this might help you in some way.

Regards.

Comment: a) no need for a global hammer b) never fiddle in classes/bin folder

Comment: @kleopatra : Please put some more light on Global Hammer(Define the term, please show me what I am missing). You always do act like a wizard for me, to learn something new :-)  Regards